# Draw dashed line in a WPF adorner

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, graphics

I have found several articles on the Web regarding drawing a dashed line in WPF. However, they seem to revolve around using the Line-class, which is a UIElement in WPF. It goes something like this:

```
Line myLine = new Line();
DoubleCollection dashes = new DoubleCollection();
dashes.Add(2);
dashes.Add(2);
myLine.StrokeDashArray = dashes;
```

Now, I am inside an Adorner, where I only have access to a Drawing Context. There, I am more or less reduced to the Drawing primitives, Brushes, Pens, geometry etc. This looks more like that:

```
var pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(200, 10, 20)), 2);
drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, point1, point2);
```

I am stuck how to do a dashed line on this level of the API. I hope it isn't down to "draw the small lines one by one" but rather something else I haven't seen...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Look at the [Pen.DashStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pen.dashstyle.aspx) property. You can either use members of the [DashStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.media.dashstyles.aspx) class which give some predefined dash styles, or you can specify you own pattern of dashes and gaps by creating a new [DashStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.dashstyle.aspx) instance.

```
var pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(200, 10, 20)), 2);
pen.DashStyle = DashStyles.Dash;
drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, point1, point2);
```

Comment: Doh, that's it, somehow I missed that property. It's 35+°C in Germany right now :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not stuck to primitives. If you follow this pattern, you can add anything to an adorner.

```
public class ContainerAdorner : Adorner
{
    // To store and manage the adorner's visual children.
    VisualCollection visualChildren;

    // Override the VisualChildrenCount and GetVisualChild properties to interface with 
    // the adorner's visual collection.
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount { get { return visualChildren.Count; } }
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index) { return visualChildren[index]; }

    // Initialize the ResizingAdorner.
    public ContainerAdorner (UIElement adornedElement)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);
        visualChildren.Add(_Container);
    }
    ContainerClass _Container= new ContainerClass();

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        // desiredWidth and desiredHeight are the width and height of the element that's being adorned.  
        // These will be used to place the Adorner at the corners of the adorned element.  
        double desiredWidth = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
        double desiredHeight = AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;

        FrameworkElement fe;
        if ((fe = AdornedElement as FrameworkElement) != null)
        {
            desiredWidth = fe.ActualWidth;
            desiredHeight = fe.ActualHeight;
        }

        _Container.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight));

        return finalSize;
    }
}
```